# How to retrieve all the rows which matching condition in JDBC?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, jdbc

There is a table with 3 columns, name, id and roll no. Column name value might repeat in some condition creating multiple row for 1 name.

I am creating an application where I have to type the name to search, and in result, it must display the name, id and rollno. If in case there are multiple rows for the searched name, all the row must be visible in the front end.

I am using jdbc and mssql server to retrieve the data, in my case only the first row are getting displayed in the result. How should I retrieve all the rows with the searched name. Below is the sample code:

```
try {
    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);

    PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("select * from NG_RLOS_VW_CURRENT_UAB_PRICING where name="+"'"+myText+"'");
    ResultSet rs1 = ps.executeQuery();
    ResultSet rs2 = ps.getResultSet();
    ResultSetMetaData rsm = rs2.getMetaData();

            while(rs1.next()){
                name=rs1.getString(1);
                id=rs1.getInt(2);
                roll_no=rs1.getInt(3);  
            }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your SQL code. Are you sure you are searching by name having several records?

Comment: yes the record for 1 name can occur multiple time, but in the front end, only the first row results are coming, how to display another row.

Comment: Why are you getting both `rs1` and `rs2`, that doesn't make sense, neither does getting the result set meta data and then doing nothing with it. Also using `getFloat` for something called `name` seems a bit weird. But without a full [mcve] it would be a bit hard for us to tell you exactly what is wrong.

Comment: there is nothing to do with rs2. Please ignore that. I was just examining it. Also I have edited my code. My requirement is simple, if running the above query i.e 'Select * from ....' gets more than 1 row with the same name, then how to display all the row in the front end. Does I have to do any iteration or similar. I just want to display all the row, currently it displays only the first row. In the simplest way, I have to iterate each row, how do I can do that?

Comment: "I have to iterate each row, how do I can do that?" - You are already doing it; that's what the `while (rs1.next())` loop does. You're just not doing anything meaningful with the results from each row.

Comment: Are you sure you are getting the first row, because by the looks of it (as Gord indicates in his comments), you may actually be getting the **last** row, as you are continuously overwriting the same variables (or fields) in your code, while doing nothing meaningful in the loop itself. That means that after you have read the last row, you will only have a single set of values, that of the last row.